# Clustering with Unique Class Requirement

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I have a dataset where there are 100 features for a each data point, along with a "year" class ranging from 1965 to 2010. I have 1000 data points for each "year" class. I want to cluster the data point based on the 100 features, not including the "year" associated with it, but I want the year class to act as rules for valid clusters. Which algorithm should I use for the following desired results:

- Produce 10 clusters based on the 100 features, where each unique "year" class is fully contained within a single cluster
- Product 10 clusters based on the 100 features, where each cluster contains only objects of consecutive years. I.e. cluster one has all objects from 1965-1980, cluster two has all objects with classes from 1980-1981, etc.

I know the second one can be particularly difficult, but can anyone direct me to which algorithm I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your data.

You want to have **one record per year**.

Then you can compute the similarities of years and use hierarchical clustering.

It's also easy to modify hierarchical clustering to only allow merging "adjacent" years, for your second condition.

This will also make things a lot faster: you only have 45 years, and in the latter case, only 1-2 neighbors each.

Comment: Thanks, this is already really helpful! How can I use all the data I have for all the years to make the clustering more accurate? Should I take the mean of each feature for each year, or should I run the algorithm with random sampling for each year and merge the results somehow?

Comment: I'd consider time series similarities, pairwise comparisons, etc.